Why is my new Kawasaki Ninja 650 making strange sounds and feels unstable in this case?
I recently bought a new Kawasaki Ninja 650, and I've been experiencing some unusual symptoms. Here are the details:
Motorcycle Details:
Model: Kawasaki Ninja 650
Purchased: 4 months ago
First Service: Completed at 1500 km
Current Mileage: 3000 km
Symptoms:
Unusual Sound During Acceleration:
When I twist the throttle, there's an additional sound similar to scraping or hissing, which is more noticeable at lower RPMs.
Buzzing and Humming at High RPMs:
There is a specific buzzing and humming noise that occurs at relatively high engine speeds.
Normal Performance at Higher Speeds:
The bike runs perfectly fine at higher speeds (around 100 km/h or more). There are no issues with acceleration or power.
Issues at Lower Speeds:
When riding at lower speeds (10-30 km/h in corners and accelerating, the bike feels like it's slipping or as if the Kawasaki Traction Control (KTRC) is activating. This is just the sensation I get; I don't think the KTRC is malfunctioning because the bike is brand new.
Any suggestions on what to check next or how to diagnose these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Don't bike manufacturers have specific break-in procedures for their bikes? Also, if there's any issues, should this be covered under warranty?

Hi, thank you for your comment.
It should be covered under warranty, but I am still interested what could it be before I go back home and bring it to the service. :)
